# Correct Enum Value

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, enums

I want to get a value of Enum.In here i get value as enumVal.ToCharArray()[0].But it's not correct.(When i select Received in dropdownlist then value shows me 88 (R's Char
array value,BUT i want Received's value is 1)
My Code

```
var LetterTypeList = new List<LetterStatusModel>();
foreach (var item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(LetterStatus)))
{
string enumVal = item.ToString();
LetterTypeList.Add(new LetterStatusModel { LetterStatusCode = enumVal.ToCharArray()[0], LetterStatusName = enumVal });
}


public class LetterStatusModel
{
public int LetterStatusCode { get; set; }
public string LetterStatusName { get; set; }

}


public enum LetterStatus
{
Received = 1,
Issued = 2,
Paused = 3,
Cancel = 4,
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of taking the name of the value by doing `ToString()`, you can cast the value to an int:

```
int enumValue = (int)item;
```

Comment: enumVal item comes like "Received"

Comment: So what is the value for `enumValue`? Did you test this?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, I asked you what the value was for `enumValue` as I posted the code, and you keep referring to `enumVal`...